# Python pygame adding ball collision with barrier

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, collision-detection

https://gist.github.com/KwakMinSeok/3f5511fd277059c741e31f296b02a868

I'm making simulation.. while i'm making it, i added barrier inside.. but i have no ides how to add collision with barriers, I tried lots of things but the inheritance of the parent didn't work. could you guys please help me...I left url of my github before adding my failed collision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't have built-in buttons. But they have all you would need to make one, like creating boxes, getting mouse position and knowing when the user clicked on the mouse etc. Therefore it is common to implement buttons yourself (especially in `PyGame`, I have used `turtle-graphics` only a little bit). Here is a great tutorial on how to do that for PyGame:
https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-buttons-part-1-button-rectangle/